# How can I remove margins when integrating matplotlib plots with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, margins, matplotlib

The python plotting library matplotlib will by default add margins to any plot that it generates. They can be reduced to a certain degree through some options of `savefig()`, namely `bbox_inches='tight'` and `pad_inches=0`. Even with those options, some margins will always remain, though.

If a plot generated by matplotlib is to be used in conjunction with pgfplots and the `addplot graphics` feature, those margins need to be predictable (and ideally non-existent).

**Q**: How can these margins be got rid of completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)
plt.savefig('out.pdf')
```

[image: plot without margins]

This generates a sine plot completely without margins. The resulting pdf can then be integrated into a pgfplots plot like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    plot graphics/xmin=0,
    plot graphics/xmax=10,
    plot graphics/ymin=-1,
    plot graphics/ymax=1,
    enlargelimits=false]
    \addplot graphics {out};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This line 
    `extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())` gave unexpected result in my case as well as the `bbox_inches="tight"`. I replaced it by `subplots_adjust(left=0., right=1., top=1., bottom=0.)` and no bbox_inches option.

Comment: Interesting; that sounds a lot less hackish. Would you be willing to make this into a complete code snippet and post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You may as well add it to your answer. Thanks.